# Find specific element from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a multidimensional array that I use to build a navigation menu. It may consist of any number of submenus (or children). The menu works just fine. When someone clicks on a menu link, the product category with id "menuid" opens. However, I also need to know the menuid of all the children of the current menuid (but not it's grandchildren and so forth).

This is an example of the array:

```
    Array
(
   [0] => Array
      (
         [menutype] => url
         [menuid] => 46
      )
   [1] => Array
      (
         [menutype] => product_category
         [menuid] => 55
         [children] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                  (
                     [menutype] => product_category
                     [menuid] => 69
                     [children] => Array
                        (
                           [0] => Array
                              (
                                 [menutype] => product_category
                                 [menuid] => 211
                              )
                           [1] => Array
                              (
                                 [menutype] => product_category
                                 [menuid] => 57
                              )
                           [2] => Array
                              (
                                 [menutype] => product_category
                                 [menuid] => 166
                              )
                        )
                  )
               [1] => Array
                  (
                     [menutype] => product_category
                     [menuid] => 57
                  )
               [2] => Array
                  (
                     [menutype] => product_category
                     [menuid] => 94
                  )
            )
      )
   [2] => Array
      (
         [menutype] => posts_category
         [menuid] => 45
      )
)
```

For example, I would like to know how to get the **menuid** value of the elements in **children** for the element with menuid 69. (Should return an array with 211, 57 and 166).

Comment: What code do you have for the menu that _works just fine_

Comment: The easiest way is to build a *recursive function*  Basically a function that you will pass an array into, and then *if there's a child array* you'll call the function from *within* the function.  There's many examples online.

Comment: AbraCadaver The code for the menu is too extensive to post here, especially since it's not relevant. :) The array in my post has been edited, there are a lot more data in each element of the original array (in addition to menutype, menuid and children).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a recursive function like so:

```
function getChildIds($menuItems, $parentId) {
    foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
        if (isset($menuItem['children'])) {
            $result = getChildIds($menuItem['children'], $parentId);
            if ($result !== false) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
        if ($menuItem['menuid'] == $parentId) {
            $result = [];
            if (isset($menuItem['children'])) {
                foreach ($menuItem['children'] as $childItem) {
                    $result[] = $childItem['menuid'];
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note this will return an empty array if the menuid is found but has no children, or false if the id is not found.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Worked right out of the box (had to correct the misspelling of "children", though). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also You can use recursive function with more efficient way like this:

```
$menu = [
    [
        'menutype' => 'url',
        'menuid'   => 46,
    ],
    [
        'menutype' => 'product_category',
        'menuid'   => 55,
        'children' => [
            [
                'menutype' => 'product_category',
                'menuid'   => 69,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'menutype' => 'product_category',
                        'menuid'   => 211
                    ],
                    [
                        'menutype' => 'product_category',
                        'menuid'   => 57
                    ],
                    [
                        'menutype' => 'product_category',
                        'menuid'   => 166
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'menutype' => 'product_category',
                'menuid'   => 57
            ],
            [
                'menutype' => 'product_category',
                'menuid'   => 94
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'menutype' => 'posts_category',
        'menuid'   => 45
    ]
];

function getMenu(array $menu, $menuId, $children = true)
{
    foreach ($menu as $menuItem) {
        if (array_key_exists('menuid', $menuItem) && $menuItem['menuid'] == $menuId) {
            if ($children === true && array_key_exists('children', $menuItem)){
                return $menuItem['children'];
            }

            return $menuItem;
        }

        if (array_key_exists('children', $menuItem)) {
            return getMenu($menuItem['children'], $menuId, $children);
        }
    }
}

getMenu($menu, 69);
```